# Getting my student loan wiped

Tags: united-states

Recently my college was [sued and lost due to false advertisement/fraud](https://www.ftc.gov/enforcement/cases-proceedings/refunds/devry-refunds-debt-forgiveness).  I have received a check in the mail as part of my payout due to this. I have also noticed many people in the [comment sections of this page](https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/blog/ftc-sends-devry-refund-checks) were mentioning a process in which I could potentially go to the student aid website and request that my student loans be forgiven under the grounds of fraud committed by the school.  Is this just people talking angrily or do I have legit potential to appeal my student loans?

If I have a legit argument, would I be able to get back what I paid into the loans or simply just not have to make another payment?

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I can understand why you would think that however I am asking about student loans and how I can proceed with them, not about legal issues with the case.  If the community here though thinks it would be better asked there, then I can, however, I would imagine that asking about student loans there would be off topic.

Comment: You write: "do I have legit potential to appeal my student loans?" I'm not familiar with US, but this seems to me something that can only be answered by someone expert about law.

Comment: @ggiaquin You're asking a question about your legal rights. It happens to be about student loans but it's primarily a legal question. Of course, student loans are intrinsically a part of academia but this particular aspect of them is unlikely to be familiar to many people here.

Comment: @DavidRicherby okay no problem! sorry guys I will further this on to Law then.  Thank you for your time!

Comment: No worries. You can flag your question and ask the moderators to move it over to law, and then the answer will move with it.

Answer (score 6):

As per [this page from the FTC regarding DeVry](https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/blog/did-you-attend-devry-dont-pay-loan-forgiveness):

> So what can you do if you think you might be a candidate for loan forgiveness or are looking for other help with your student loans?
>
> - If you’ve got federal loans, go to the Department of Education’s [StudentAid.gov](https://studentaid.ed.gov/sa/repay-loans/forgiveness-cancellation) to find out more about applying for forgiveness and cancellation, or other programs like income-driven repayment plans. Information about one kind of loan forgiveness, known as a borrower defense discharge, is available [here](https://www.studentaid.gov/borrower-defense).  Applying for any of these programs is free.
> - If you’ve got private loans, try contacting your loan servicer directly to see what options you might have.

You may way want to consider contacting a lawyer who's familiar with this area of expertise for more information, but as the above article mentions, **do not trust or pay any company who says they can get your loans forgiven for a fee.**

Comment: Thanks for this, would anyone in the law SE be able to clarify if this situation would apply for cancellation/forgiveness?